# Migrating a non standard layout svn repository to git

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a local svn repository with a non standard layout, i.e., without trunk, branches and tags and with many "flat" projects. It's like this:

```
<repo root>/project1/<source files>
<repo root>/project2/<source files>
...
```

I want each project to get into a separate git repo.

I'm doing the authors conversion step **1** as described in [this guide](https://gist.github.com/epicserve/1219858/9f30d5ffca7d6b6e4130c4b9b300b8167c868a5f)

and then using this command instead of the one in step **2**:

```
cd <repo root>/project1/
git svn clone file:///<path to root>/project1 --no-metadata -T ./ --authors-file=authors-transform.txt ~/temp.git
```

I don't use the `--stdlayout`, because I don't have such layout, and I also use the `-T` option to denote where the trunk should be found for this repo. The step seems to run ok, and ~/temp.git contains the source files of the project. I can see the commit logs and the change in there with `git log`, `git diff`.

Then I'm executing next two steps as they are given in the guide.
Step **4** gives the following output:

```
$ git push bare
Counting objects: 534, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (499/499), done.
Writing objects: 100% (534/534), 281.99 KiB | 2.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 534 (delta 261), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (261/261), done.
To /home/thanos/new-bare.git
 * [new branch]      origin/trunk -> origin/trunk
```

which I don't know if it's correct. Step **5** is then failing:

```
$ git branch -m trunk master
error: refname refs/heads/trunk not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

Any clue what I 'm doing wrong? Is the use of `-T` in step ***2*** correct? And the no use of `--stdlayout`?

Comment: You don't have branch `trunk` so you cannot rename it; you only have `origin/trunk`.

Comment: Thanks! Based on this input I modified the symbolic link creation in step 4 into: ```git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/origin/trunk``` and also branch rename in step 5 into: ```git branch -m origin/trunk master```. Step 6 worked as is. Now I'm able to ```git clone``` the new-bare.git and I see my code with the log commits and everything. Please answer the question so I can vote it, and upload final steps for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - [new branch]      origin/trunk -> origin/trunk

You don't have branch `trunk` so you cannot rename it; you have `origin/trunk`.